# Renombrar un archivo con la información en el input=text

Tags: javascript, php, imagen, fileupload

un saludo a la comunidad, resulta que necesito de su ayuda.
es un formulario para subir un archivo pero que el archivo que se suba se renombre con la información que esta en el campo "nuevo nombre",

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple> <br>
  <label>Nuevo Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="cod" name="cod"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" /><br>
</form>
<script src="upload.js"></script>
```

el contenido del archivo upload.js es este:

```
const url = 'process.php';
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const cod = document.querySelector('cod');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault();

const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
 const  cod = document.querySelector('[type=text]').cod;
const formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];

    formData.append('files[]', file);
    formData.append('cod', cod);
}

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then(response => {
    return response.text();
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

y el contenido del archivo process.php es este:

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = [];
    $path = 'images/';
$extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
    
    $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {  
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($tmp));

    $file = $path . trim($_POST['cod']) .".png";

    if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
        $errors[] = 'Extension not allowed: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
    }

    if ($file_size > 2097152) {
        $errors[] = 'File size exceeds limit: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
    }
    }

   if ($errors) print_r($errors);
   }
   }
   ?>
```

La imagen si se sube, pero no lo renombra con la información del campo "nuevo nombre" sino que lo pone como "undefined.png"...

Si alguien puede ayudarme por favor, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cod` no es una propiedad de js.

Cuando cambias un valor de un `input` lo que estás cambiando es el `value` de un elemento js. Entonces para obtener el valor debes poner

```
const  cod = document.querySelector('[type=text]').value;
```

en lugar de

```
const  cod = document.querySelector('[type=text]').cod;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas a lo que me refiero.

```js
const change = () => {
  const  cod = document.querySelector('[type=text]').cod;
  const  value = document.querySelector('[type=text]').value;
  console.log(`valor de cod es ${cod}`);
  console.log(`valor de value es ${value}`);
}
```

```html
<p>Escribe sobre el input para ver el cambio</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="cod" name="cod" onkeypress="change()"> <br>
</form>
```

Para enviarlo sin presionar submit, usa `onchange` en el `input type="file"`. cuando cambie, entonces buscas el `form` y luego le haces `submit` al form.

NOTA: Debes cambiarle el nombre al botón ya que al ser llamado como la función del submit genera problemas, en este caso yo le puse a tu botón `btnsubmit`

```js
const change = () => {
  const  cod = document.querySelector('[type=text]').cod;
  const  value = document.querySelector('[type=text]').value;
  console.log(`valor de cod es ${cod}`);
  console.log(`valor de value es ${value}`);
}

const onLoadImage = () => {
 const form = document.getElementById('form');
 console.log(form.submit())
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="onLoadImage()"> <br>
  <label>Nuevo Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="cod" name="cod" onkeypress="change()"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnsubmit" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente! hice el cambio y funciona de maravilla...

Comment: ahora, una pregunta mas... como puedo hacer para que al seleccionar el  archivo se suba automaticamente?

Comment: A qué te refieres? a que subas el archivo y no tengas que presionar el botón de submit?

Comment: Exactamente, que solo se suba y no tenga que presionar submit

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que se suba en automático.

Comment: He probado, y me da error al llamar la funcion onloadimage(), lo tengo que poner el script en index. o en upload.js?

Comment: Mientras esta función se encuentre definida antes del `fom` estará bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha funcionado de maravilla! Dios te bendiga

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada, para en caso de que alguien tenga la misma pregunta que tú